# Change colour of table row onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onclick

I have created a table having rows with alternating colours(say yellow and red). Now, I want to change the colour of the clicked row to one common colour(say blue).And revert back to its original colour when clicked again. 
I'm able to change the colour using this code

```
$("#mainTable").find('#'+IDClicked).css("background-color", "#bbbbff");
```

I'm not able to figure out how to revert back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We **assume** that your code this this way:

#### HTML

```
<table id="rowClick">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### In that case, you can use jQuery this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rowClick > tr").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

#### And finally the CSS part:

```
table tr.active {background: #ccc;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/icusec/2

Comment: Wow!! U gave me an answer really fast.. but i cant accept it fast enough! :) Perfectly resolved.. Thank you!

Comment: Sure... :) Welcome, also added fiddle! :)

Comment: without jquery?

Comment: @Sith2021 There are lots of ways you can do it using `document.querySelectorAll`... `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this below code

**CSS**

```
.high-light{background:blue !important;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('table tr').click(function(){ $(this).addClass("high-light");  });
 //If you have TD's background set try the below commented code
  $('table tr td').click(function(){ $(this).parent().find('td').addClass("high-light");  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Answering exactly to your question:**

```
$('#box').on('click', function() {
    var box$ = $(this),
        isBgColorChanged = box$.data('isBgColorChanged'),
        bgColor = !!isBgColorChanged ? '#444' : '#ccc';
    box$.css('background-color', bgColor)
        .data('isBgColorChanged', !isBgColorChanged);
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/4UD7x/)

**More elegant solution:**

```
$('#box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('activated');
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/myJbH/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/ufPcs/2/)**:

```
$('table tr').toggle(function(){
$(this).addClass('myclass');
}, function(){
$(this).removeClass('myclass');
});​
```

**css**

```
.myclass{
background: red;
}

table tr{
 background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: You can use `toggleClass()`, which just does the same!

Comment: @PraveenKumar, i just want to which will execute fast and better solution?