# AngularJS : change panel header background based on click

Tags: angularjs

I have a panel header which I have divided into 2 parts.

when I click on one panel then its background is **sky blue** and text color is **white** while other panel background is **gray** with **black** text color and clicking on that panel background and text color is changed alternatively.

```css
.prefix_event {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f2f1f1;
  color: #555555;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.prefix_previous {
  text-align: center;
  background: #24b6e3;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="panel panel-default set_padding_0 set_margin_0">
      <div class="panel-heading set_padding_0 set_margin_0 cursor_pointer">
        <div class="row set_margin_0">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center prefix_previous" ng-click="option='event_exhibitors'" ng-init="option='event_exhibitors'">
            Event Exhibitors
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center prefix_event" ng-click="option='previous_exhibitors'">
            Previous Exhibitors
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" ng-show="option==='event_exhibitors'">
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="inner-addon right-addon col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search_icon_color"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="panel-body" ng-show="option==='previous_exhibitors'">
        <div class="row ">
          <p>Previous Exhibitors</p>
          <p>Previous Exhibitors</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i want is. when clicking on **previous exhibitors** panel. the background color and text color of **event exhibitors** should be given to **previous exhibitors** and **event_exhibitors** should get previous exhibitors background and text color. so it will be vice versa CSS on click.

Any help would be great.

Comment: where is your angular code here?

Comment: ng-click, ng-init, ng-show.

Comment: can you add more explanation?

Comment: You didn't include `ng-app` directive that's why its not working. Let me edit

Comment: what i want is. when clicking on **previous exhibitors** panel. the background color and text color of **event exhibitors** should be given to **previous exhibitors** and **event_exhibitors** should get **previous exhibitors** background and text color. so it will be vice versa CSS on click.

Comment: @SankarRaj.. yeah.. thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple using the toggle option like this in the

```
$scope.toggle="false";
```

Your HTML will be like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="panel panel-default set_padding_0 set_margin_0">
        <div class="panel-heading set_padding_0 set_margin_0 cursor_pointer">
          <div class="row set_margin_0">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center prefix_previous"
            ng-click="toggle = !toggle" 
            ng-class="{prefix_event : toggle, prefix_previous : !toggle}"
            >
              Event Exhibitors
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center prefix_event" 
         ng-click="toggle = !toggle" 
            ng-class="{'prefix_previous' : toggle}"
         >
              Previous Exhibitors
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" ng-show="option==='event_exhibitors'">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="inner-addon right-addon col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search_icon_color"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="panel-body" ng-show="option==='previous_exhibitors'">
          <div class="row ">
            <p>Previous Exhibitors</p>
            <p>Previous Exhibitors</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9ZYHs4Ba0pDAGEcFZFsT?p=preview)

UPDATE 1 : Also check the modified plunker in the same link

Change these @ **Previous Exhibitors**

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-show="!toggle">
```

Change these @ **Event Exhibitors**

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-show="toggle">
```

Comment: clicking on previous exhibitors panel , its content is not showing

Comment: Happy to help u

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this functionality with simple Jquery.

[Change colour of table row onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970634/change-colour-of-table-row-onclick)

and if you use class="col-xs-12" then it overrides other higher sizes as well and make them 12(col-sm-12,col-md-12,col-lg-12).

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: thank you.. but i don't want to use jQuery. that's why